# Assigning Picklist value to other picklist

Tags: visualforce

I have 2 picklist. Picklist1 with values:- Test1,Test2,Test3 and Picklist2 with same values.
In vf page .. when a user selects Test1 in Pikclist1 then Picklist2 should be automatically updated with value as Test1

Code

```
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
         <apex:outputLabel value="Picklist1"/>
         <apex:actionRegion immediate="true">
         <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Picklist1__c}" label="Picklist1">
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="pbs3" />
         </apex:inputField>
        </apex:actionRegion>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs3" columns="1">
        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Picklist1__c}"    label="Picklist2" required="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: I can think of 2 ways of doing this: 1) using javascript, fire the script onChange, get the value from picklist1 and then assign it in the picklist2.  2) using only apex by using the <apex:actionRegion> with reRender attribute. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried with actionregion... but..in value field of Picklist2 if i give as '{!acc.Pikclist1}'then on save its not saving the values for picklist2 in database

Comment: Either of the above mentioned approaches by @theGreatDanton should work.

Comment: @TestNS: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for actionRegion?

Comment: and also added answer

Answer (score 1):

Its working now.
Working code

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
         <apex:outputLabel value="Picklist1"/>
         <apex:actionRegion immediate="true">
         <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Picklist1__c}" label="Picklist1">
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!copy}" rerender="pbs3" />
         </apex:inputField>
        </apex:actionRegion>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs3" columns="1">
        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Picklist2__c}"    label="Picklist2" required="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

Class code
public pageReference copy()
{
this.acc.picklist2 = this.acc.picklist1;
}
```

Comment: The          <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Picklist1__c}"    label="Picklist2" required="true"/>
should be changed to         <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Picklist2__c}"    label="Picklist2" required="true"/>

Comment: Yep you are right